# Latex references and bibliography not working

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texmaker

I need to deliver a report using Latex. Since the beginning I have had a lot of difficulties with it, that thankfully were resolved when I started using the Texmaker tool. Unfortunately the references still do not work and I have already wasted too many hours trying to figure it out.

I have a file where I define all my references which is called refbase.bib . As an example, this is one of my entries in it:

```
 @Article{belkin:1990,
 title                    = {The cognitive viewpoint in information science},
 author                   = {Nicholas J. Belkin},
 journal                  = JIS,
 year                     = {1990},
 pages                    = {11--15},
 volume                   = {16}
}
```

For me to call these references to my the reference section of my report, I have the file references.tex and have just the following command:

```
\bibliography{./refbase}
```

My sources told me that this should call the bibliography list and make my reference page, however nothing is happening. The file is completely ignored.

Also, whenever I call a citation during the report, I will get this in it's place "(??)". The way I make the citation is as follows (also according to what the source websites tell me to do:

```
bla blabla blabla bla \cite{belkin:1990}.
```

Anyone have a clue as to what is going on and how to fix it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am unsure how texmaker works, but the logfile of the compile should contain warnings about undefined references. You should run bibtex and then pdflatex (twice) to sort this out.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminBannier. Turns out, I just needed to do exactly that, but a bunch of times consecutive... I don't know what to think of that...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soooo the problem has been solved.

Apparently I needed to run bibtex and the quickbuild many times consecutive. After about 3 times running each one, it just starts working.

I really don't know what to think of it... But as of now, at least I finally got it working.

Comment: You can also use TeXworks and its compiling option "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX". Once you do that, "quick build" with your compiler should work. (Although every time you add an entry to the `.bib` file, you need to re-run the triple compile again.)